# Calculate angle between two vectors

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$, $ad-bc\neq 0$,
$
  T= \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\\\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}.
$

For fixed $\theta$, take $L_{\theta}={(t\cos{\theta},t\sin{\theta}), \text{for}\hspace{2mm} t \ge 0 }$.
Calculate the angle between $T(L_0)$ and $T(L_{\theta})$ on $(0,0)$ in terms of $a,b,c,d,\theta$.

I want to use that $$\cos{\alpha}=\displaystyle\frac{T(L_0) \cdot T(L_{\theta})}{\||T(L_0)\||\hspace{1mm} \||T(L_{\theta})\||}$$

and the first calculations give:

$T(L_0)=t(a, b)$

$T(L_{\theta})=t(a\cos{\theta}+c\sin{\theta}, b\cos{\theta}+d\sin{\theta})$

$\||T(L_0)\||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$\||T(L_{\theta})\||=t\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\cos^2{\theta}+(c^2+d^2)\sin^2{\theta}+(2ac+2bd)\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}$

but I don't understand the point $(0,0)$ well because there $t$ vanishes then it is not possible to calculate the angle.

I appreciate if you can correct me or give me a hint

Comment: $T(L_0) = t(a,b)$. And the title is not correct, you are not computing the angle between two linear transformations, you are computing the angle between two vectors.

Comment: you have reason! thanks

Comment: How do you intend on defining the angle between a vector and the point $(0,0)$?